# Не могу отправить запрос AJAX?

Tags: php, ajax, api

Хотел дать запрос на один API с Basic Auth (USERNAME - PASSWORD).
Создал index.php - добавил заголовок `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');`
Написал скрипт - по нажатию на кнопку отправить AJAX

```
function myFunction(){
        var username="xxx";
        var password="xxx";
        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "xxx",
          dataType: 'json',
          headers: {
            "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password)
          },
          success: function (result){
              console.log(result)
          }
        });
```

В ответ получаю

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'xxx' from origin 'https://Мой серв.kz' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Comment: Если вы отсылаете этот запрос на сервер, отвечающий вам это, то тогда только через серверный код, которому заколовок Access-Control-Allow-Origin не важен. Скорее всего сервер не поддерживает клиентские (JS) запросы с использованием авторизации, вам нужно использовать PHP вместо Javascript для отсылки запроса через CURL, к примеру.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov так он на свой "другой" сервер отправляет, насколько я понимаю, и там добавил заголовок. Возможно, добавил не в том месте где-то (после вывода), или не во всех, где надо было (был редирект).